# Cross-DLL calls

Tags: dll, c++11

When considering cross-DLL calls, if I guarantee that both DLLs use the same compiler and dynamically link to the (same) run-time libraries, does that mean that things like delete and throw will work correctly across the boundary? If not, is there anything that can make such possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, no problem.  Do a clean build occasionally to catch circular dependencies.